# MailChimp Add Subscriber using API 3.0 PHP

Tags: php, html, mailchimp

I am trying to add a php file that adds a new subscriber to my MailChimp list. Here is my form that SHOULD trigger the php file to add the new subscriber:

```
<form action="/scripts/freemonth_action.php" class="email_form_freemonth" method="post">
    <h3>Get your first month free</h3>
    <div class="form-group customised-formgroup"> <span class="icon-user"></span>
        <input type="text" name="full_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group customised-formgroup"> <span class="icon-envelope"></span>
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <!--<div class="form-group customised-formgroup"> <span class="icon-telephone"></span>
        <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone (optional)">
    </div>-->
    <div class="form-group customised-formgroup"> <span class="icon-laptop"></span>
        <input type="text" name="website" class="form-control" placeholder="Website (optional)">
    </div>
    <!--<div class="form-group customised-formgroup"> <span class="icon-bubble"></span>
        <textarea name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    </div>-->
    <div>
        <br>
        <button style="margin: 0 auto" type="submit" class="btn btn-fill full-width">GET FREE MONTH<span class="icon-chevron-right"></span></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

And here is freemonth_action.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = trim($_POST['full_name']);
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    if(!empty($email) && !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false){
        // MailChimp API credentials
        $apiKey = '6b610769fd3353643c7427db98d43ad6-us16';
        $listID = '0cf013d1d9';

        // MailChimp API URL
        $memberID = md5(strtolower($email));
        $dataCenter = substr($apiKey,strpos($apiKey,'-')+1);
        $url = 'https://' . $dataCenter . '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' . $listID . '/members/' . $memberID;

        // member information
        $json = json_encode([
            'email_address' => $email,
            'status'        => 'subscribed',
            'merge_fields'  => [
                'NAME'     => $name,
            ]
        ]);

        // send a HTTP POST request with curl
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:' . $apiKey);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($ch);
        echo json_encode($result);

        // store the status message based on response code
        if ($httpCode == 200) {
            $_SESSION['msg'] = '<p style="color: #34A853">You have successfully subscribed to CodexWorld.</p>';
        } else {
            switch ($httpCode) {
                case 214:
                    $msg = 'You are already subscribed.';
                    break;
                default:
                    $msg = 'Some problem occurred, please try again.';
                    break;
            }
            $_SESSION['msg'] = '<p style="color: #EA4335">'.$msg.'</p>';
        }
    }else{
        $_SESSION['msg'] = '<p style="color: #EA4335">Please enter valid email address.</p>';
    }
}
```

I'm not even sure how to debug this, because when i do echo $result (or anything like that) I do not see anything on the page or logged to the console. I'm also open to any suggestions that use javascript as long as it is still the 3.0 API.

Comment: Im not sure about the MailChimp API rules but normally you would `json_decode()` the result instead of `json_encode()` at the end.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks. And would that print to the document or log to console?

Comment: that would convert the data MailChimp sent back to from JSON to array. You can then manipulate the array to print to console or anything else.

Comment: Just a heads up, you might want to edit your question and remove the api key (if it's real).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your subscription code works fine. The reason you aren't seeing any result is because `isset($_POST['submit'])` looks for an element with the name 'submit' rather than the type 'submit'. Just add the `name` attribute to your button, and it should work for you:

```
<button style="margin: 0 auto" type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-fill full-width">GET FREE MONTH<span class="icon-chevron-right"></span></button>
```

Also, you should keep the API key secret so other people can't access your MailChimp account through the API. I'd recommend disabling your current key and creating a new one. See MailChimp's knowledgebase article about [API Keys](https://kb.mailchimp.com/integrations/api-integrations/about-api-keys) for more details.

Comment: I added name="submit" but it is still not adding the email to my subscription list in mail chimp. I don't even see a successful api call recorded in the mail chimp api log

Comment: @Tom Are you able to get a message when you echo `$_SESSION['msg']`?

Comment: I FOUND THE PROBLEM. Joel H. was right about me forgetting to put name="submit", and the other problem was that I was getting an error message: 'Cannot convert blah to string at line 43', which was this `echo json_encode($result);`. After adding name='submit' in my html and taking out that line of php the api is now working.